# Sharp bounds for the number of groups of order $75600$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, groups-enumeration

How can I get sharp bounds for $gnu(75600)$, the number of groups of order $75600$.

I tried to determine the number of groups of order $15120$ to get a reasonable lower bound, but I quit GAP after some hours, noticing that there still was a long way to finish the calculation.

I determined $gnu(2160)=3429$ , $gnu(3024)=4635$ and $gnu(5040)=4539$, so a lower bound of $gnu(75600)$ is $gnu(3024)\cdot gnu(25)=9270$.

> Can anyone give better bounds, or even the actual value ?

Comment: Peter: you may be interested to see this: https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/tree/master/data

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Very nice! Can I download the textfile ?

Comment: Yes - text file is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/master/data/gnu50000.txt and GAP readable is  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/master/data/gnu50000.g

Comment: I could handle these files with excel and verified that there is no solution of $gnu(n)=n$ for $n>1$ under the known values upto $50000$. However, I could not read the vector with GAP. I will try to import the file in parts.

Comment: The GAP input file's size is 712 KB. It is assumed that most people will get it using Git, but you can also download it via the web-interface using the link I provided.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean - you have the file, but GAP runs our of memory. We should chat one day to see what happens under Vista.

Comment: True, the memory is the only problem.If we enter a chat-room I can show you the holes upto $10,000$ and you can verify them.

Comment: Not now, sorry (and for holes, I do suggest to use GitHub and report them as one or several new issues at https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/issues)

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Hi, are you "on air" ?

Comment: Hi - here, but not for long

Comment: I want to report two gnu's. I do it here and not on github because the result is not complete. $n=2240$ gave $10759$ groups and $1$ pair of groups, probably non-isomorphic, so the result should be $10761$. Duration : several hours on my computer. $n=2496$ gave $13088$ single groups and $3$ pairs of groups. I wanted to check them, but due to a bug (?), I could not create a list (perhaps a memory issue). So, the result is somewhere between $13091$ and $13094$. Duration: about 2 hours on my computer.

Comment: thanks - but fine to report on GitHub partial step: see how I did it myself in e.g. https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/issues/18

Comment: Hi, have any time to chat about Windows memory issues?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I have time, sorry, I was busy with a question here. By the way, I posted new gnu's on github.

Comment: seen them, and validated already. You can set up github notifications to see their updates, btw

Comment: ok, so how much RAM do you have on your machine?

Comment: How can I find that out ?

Comment: is it Windows Vista?

Comment: I think, yes, it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39819/discussion-between-alexander-konovalov-and-peter).

Comment: Now  gnu(37800)=17031 - see https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/issues/26#issuecomment-229957277

Answer (score 4):

There are (usual method -- calculation with GAP) 22758 groups of order 15120. The calculation took about 2 days. I don't see a fundamental obstacle to running order 75600, but that might take a week or two.

Comment: Did you check that the groups are actually non-isomorphic ?

Comment: This is the result of `ConstructAllGroups` which already uses some isomorphism tests, I did not try to determine distinguishing invariants or ran explicit isomorphism tests on the result.

Comment: For me, `r:=ConstructAllGroups(15120)` took 72hrs, the resulting list has length 22758 and `ForAll(r,IsGroup)` returns `true` meaning that the result has no lists of groups that the algorithm did not not manage to distinguish (otherwise, the list `r` would have elements which are lists themselves).

Comment: @ahulpke: I've added an entry for gnu(15120) at https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/blob/master/gnudata.g. Thinking of crowdsourcing the database of gnu(n).

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thank you for cross-checking the result. It would be very nice if a database of the known gnu's would be available.

Comment: For integer factorizations, such a database exists : http://factordb.com/

Comment: @Peter: you can now submit individual Gnu(n) as new issues [here](https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/issues/new). See also [README](https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/blob/master/README.md). Maybe you can start with walking through your questions on Gnu(n) on this site (in this case,include their URL in the issues).

Comment: Where can I see the known values and the "holes" ?

Comment: Use "@" to ping - I am not seeing your replies otherwise, and there is no guarantee that I am revisiting this page. For known values, the README mentions `gnudata` file. Holes - those not covered by Small Groups Library and sglppow and those beyond being reasonably computable with cubefree.

Comment: Hi @Peter - please have a look at https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/blob/master/WISHLIST.md

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I would like to establish a full database availabe for everyone (without registration and without the need of a download), but I still have doubts of the reliability of the values. I remember I asked for a special gnu, two different method showed the same value, but it was wrong. That might mean that GAP still has some bugs or other issues. What do you mean. Which of the values $gnu(1)-gnu(2000)$ are really reliable ?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov If I could be sure that constructallgroups is absolutely reliable, I could calculate most of the values myself, unless the annyoing breakdown due to memory lack prevents this. I would suggest that everyone who found a new gnu can submit it and after it has been checked, it should be added to the database, like in the factordb-site. I see no reason why the gnu's should keep secret, I doubt that someone uses them to encrypt messages :)

Comment: Yes, crowdsourcing this collection is exactly my intention. I've submitted three entries myself today to show examples how this would work. There is no need for the user to register, and one could use any SCSCP client to connect to it without downloading the data.

Comment: I think you mean the typo in the formula which was fixed in new SglPPow: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/619365/. That was not related to `ConstructAllGroups`. The Small Group Library for n in `[1..2000]`  seem stable and is part of both GAP and Magma. Random checks confirm numbers. Full check would make a good answer to  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1607517/.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I tried to calculate $gnu(3888)$ . After several hours I got a list of $20,051$ groups and $7$ pairs of groups. Can you verify the final result that I got : $gnu(3888)=20,065$ ?

Comment: @Peter: thanks. How pairs are counted in the number 20065? If you were unable to split them or show their isomorphism, it may be too early to claim gnu(3888).

Comment: @Peter: because http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grpconst/htm/CHAP003.htm says "However, in some cases the output might contain lists of groups as well. The groups is such a list could not be proved to be pairwise non-isomorphic by the algorithm, although this is likely to be the case, see Section Verifying non-isomorphism for further details."

Comment: then http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grpconst/htm/CHAP004.htm#SECT004 says "If DistinguishGroups fails to split up the input list completely, then a user might use the general purpose function IsomorphismGroups to prove the non-isomorphism between the remaining groups. However, this might be a time consuming computation." and that's what is necessary to do

Comment: I used the distinguishedgroups-function and set the boolean variable to "true" and the result was "true". So, probably, the $14$ groups were non-isomorphic. In this case, the result came immediately, but I have a small amount of doubt, whether the result is actually true.

Comment: Documentation for `DistinguishGroups` says that it "It returns a similar list, where the sublists contained in list are split up". In this case, it does not change the structure of the input list, so it's not enough. I've checked that they are non-isomorphic using `IsomorphismGroups` instead - see https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/commit/ec2f9d18b98d1907343f3aeb2dcaf02c2f968640

Comment: @ahulpke: instead of a week or two, it still runs for me for 56 days already in GAP 4.8.3: https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/issues/26